# How can I generate .rmd files with param values set programmatically

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have been using [this solution](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html) to generate r-markdown reports from an interactive (Shiny) app.

Rather than generate and download a html file, I'm looking generate the corresponding .rmd file, since I want to be able to rerun the report with fixed settings at a later point in time.

To provide an example, using the template provided in the link, and for n=40, I want to generate a file containing the following code:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: 40
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```
````

In other words, a file in which the placeholder 'NA' from the template is replaced by the actual used value of 40.

Short of manipulating the yaml in the file directly, is there a way to set new parameters in a rmd template and generate the resulting .rmd file?

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple version to help with your parameters Rmarkdown question. This requires Rstudio. Instead of regularly knitting your document, you `knit with parameters...`

[image]

Now we get a GUI interface where we can specify the value we want, in this case we made it "numeric"

[image]

```
---
title: My Document
output: html_document
params:
    input: numeric
---


`r params$input`
```

Which renders and includes our interactive parameter inside the Rmarkdown HTML rendered document. resources I used for research: [resource 1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html) and [resource 2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html#knit-with-custom-parameters). You can do wayy more with parameters, but this was a simple answer to help provide you with an answer to your question.

[image]